# Unreal point light error message

Tags: lighting, unreal

How to fix this issue with point lights ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when you have more than 4 stationary lights overlapping.

> Only 4 or fewer overlapping stationary lights can have static shadowing, because the lights must be assigned to different channels of a shadowmap texture.

The solution then would be to make the lights not overlap or to change their shadow type to dynamic.

See [the documentation](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Engine/Rendering/LightingAndShadows/LightMobility/StationaryLights/index.html) about the correct use of these type of lights.